# What is the mineral composition of each type of ore?

Tags: eve-online

In EVE Online, each type of ore refines into one or more mineral, so for example, Veldspar regardless of type (Concentrated, Dense, etc) will always refine 100% into Tritanium.

While the information page for each ore will tell you what it breaks down into, this is pretty vague and will result in something like the following;

> With a large portion of nocxium the Hemorphite is always a good find. It is common enough that even novice miners can expect to run into it. Hemorphite also has a bit of tritanium, pyerite, mexallon and isogen as well as trace amounts of Zydrine. It requires 500 ore units to refine.

I'm more specifically interested in a breakdown for each ore of the following;

- How much ore is required to refine
- What the mineral composition of each type of ore is
- How much of each mineral you will get by refining

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As per the [Evelopedia](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Ore), this is the composition of all ores in their base variation and at 100% efficiency. The numbers denote batch size and output respectively.

**[Arkonor](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Arkonor)** - 200

- 10000 (~95.25%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 333 (~3.17%) [Megacyte](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Megacyte)
- 166 (~1.58%) [Zydrine](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Zydrine)

**[Bistot](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Bistot)** - 200

- 170 (~1.36%) [Megacyte](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Megacyte)
- 12000 (~95.92%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)
- 341 (~2.73%) [Zydrine](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Zydrine)

**[Crokite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Crokite)** - 250

- 331 (~0.85%) [Nocxium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Nocxium)
- 38000 (~97.45%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 663 (~1.70%) [Zydrine](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Zydrine)

**[Mercoxit](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mercoxit)** - 250

- 530 (100%) [Morphite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Morphite)

**[Spodumain](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Spodumain)** - 250

- 71000 (~88.56%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 140 (~0.17%) [Megacyte](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Megacyte)
- 9000 (~11.23%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)

**[Plagioclase](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Plagioclase)** - 333

- 256 (25%) [Mexallon](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mexallon)
- 256 (25%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 512 (50%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)

**[Pyroxeres](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyroxeres)** - 333

- 120 (~11.61%) [Mexallon](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mexallon)
- 11 (~1.06%) [Nocxium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Nocxium)
- 844 (~81.62%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 59 (~5.71%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)

**[Scordite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Scordite)** - 333

- 833 (~66.69%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 416 (~33.31%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)

**[Veldspar](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Veldspar)** - 333

- 1000 (100%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)

**[Dark Ochre](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Dark_Ochre)** - 400

- 500 (~1.90%) [Nocxium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Nocxium)
- 25500 (~97.14%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 250 (~0.95%) [Zydrine](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Zydrine)

**[Gneiss](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Gneiss)** - 400

- 700 (~8.50%) [Isogen](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Isogen)
- 3700 (~44.92%) [Mexallon](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mexallon)
- 3700 (~44.92%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 137 (~1.66%) [Zydrine](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Zydrine)

**[Kernite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Kernite)** - 400

- 386 (~24.98%) [Isogen](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Isogen)
- 773 (~50.03%) [Mexallon](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mexallon)
- 386 (~24.98%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)

**[Hedbergite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Hedbergite)** - 500

- 708 (~51.16%) [Isogen](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Isogen)
- 354 (~25.58%) [Nocxium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Nocxium)
- 290 (~20.95%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)
- 32 (~2.31%) [Zydrine](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Zydrine)

**[Hemorphite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Hemorphite)** - 500

- 212 (~12.97%) [Isogen](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Isogen)
- 60 (~3.67%) [Mexallon](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mexallon)
- 424 (~25.95%) [Nocxium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Nocxium)
- 650 (~39.78%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 260 (~15.91%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)
- 28 (~1.71%) [Zydrine](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Zydrine)

**[Jaspet](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Jaspet)** - 500

- 518 (50%) [Mexallon](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mexallon)
- 259 (25%) [Nocxium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Nocxium)
- 259 (25%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)

**[Omber](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Omber)** - 500

- 307 (~41.66%) [Isogen](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Isogen)
- 307 (~41.66%) [Tritanium](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Tritanium)
- 123 (~16.69%) [Pyerite](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Pyerite)

For further values (such as those for other ore variations), there is also [a spreadsheet](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mineral_composition_of_ore) on the Evelopedia. **Please note:** This spreadsheet is currently *outdated* as per the Odyssey expansion.

Comment: Now if we had table markdown that didn't require me to use extensive code blocks, I would even put that into an overly complex spreadsheet, eve style.

Comment: manually created tables are the best tables though

Comment: @kalina Not when you want to include links and multiple data points. Then they're just a pain. :P

Answer (score 3):

All of the values below are assuming the following;

- Perfect mining yield (so no minerals are lost in the refining process)
- Enough standing with the corporation whose station you're using to refine (so they don't take any ore off you)

In addition to the below, each type of ore comes in three variants, one which yields +5% to the above figures (for example, Concentrated Veldspar, Pure Jaspet, Iridescent Gneiss, etc) and one which yields +10% to the above figures (for example Dense Veldspar, Pristine Jaspet, Prismatic Gneiss, etc). These are clearly marked on the information pages for the ore itself.

#### Legend

```
Batch        Batch size for refining
TRI          Tritanium
PYE          Pyrite
MEX          Mexallon
ISO          Isogen
NOC          Nocxium
ZYD          Zydrine
MEG          Megacyte
MOR          Morphite
```

#### Refining Outputs

```
             Batch   TRI    PYE   MEX   ISO   NOC   ZYD   MEG   MOR
Veldspar      333   1000    N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A
Scordite      333    833    416   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A
Pyroxeres     333    844    59    120   N/A   11    N/A   N/A   N/A
Plagioclase   333    256    512   256   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A
Omber         500    307    123   N/A   307   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A
Kernite       400    386    N/A   773   386   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A
Jaspet        500    259    259   518   N/A   259   8     N/A   N/A
Hemorphite    500    650    260   60    212   424   28    N/A   N/A
Hedbergite    500    N/A    N/A   N/A   708   354   32    N/A   N/A
Gneiss        400   3700    N/A  3700   700   N/A   137   N/A   N/A
Dark Ochre    400   25200   N/A   N/A   N/A   500   250   N/A   N/A
Crokite       250   38000   N/A   N/A   N/A   331   663   N/A   N/A
Spodumain     250   71000  9000   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   140   N/A
Bistot        200   12000   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   341   170   N/A
Arkanor       200   10000   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   166   333   N/A
Mercoxit      250    N/A    N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   N/A   530
```

Answer (score -3):

http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Mineral_composition_of_ore

Of course, all values assume perfect refining skills.

Comment: Please expand your answer with some more information from the link.  Saves please a click.